# How to find Min and Max rows from a table including all columns from postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a view `select c1,c2,count from table` and it will give result below.

[image]

I want to fetch the entire row of maximum and minimum count's value and that should return only two rows with max and min count like below.

[image]

How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way is probably a union:

```
(
  select c1, c2, count 
  from the_table
  order by count 
  limit 1
)
union all
(
  select c1, c2, count 
  from the_table
  order by count desc
  limit 1
)
```

Usually the individual statements in a UNION, don't need parentheses, but as we want an `order by` on each of them, they are needed.

Another option would be join against a derived table:

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
  join (
    select min(count) as min_count, 
           max(count) as max_count
    from the_table
  ) mm on t1.count in (mm.min_count, mm.max_count)
```

But I doubt that this will be faster.

Comment: the above can be helpful for single set. for eg. I have one more column namely C3 and C3 is not unique for all rows. But it will repeat for few rows. In that case I want to group rows by Column C3 and find min max for each set of C3. Is that possible???

Comment: @JohnsonAnthony: please do not extend the scope of your question once you have an answer. Have a look at the current answers for [tag:greatest-n-per-group] most probably this was already answered.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(order by count) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(order by count desc) rn_desc
    from mytable t
) t
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
order by count
```

This requires scanning the table only once (as opposed to `union all` or `join`).

Comment: If there is an index on `count` the `order by ... limit 1` is usually faster. The window function requires to read all values to apply the sorting. [plan for union](https://explain.depesz.com/s/cQ0n) 
[plan for derived table](https://explain.depesz.com/s/BiuQ)
[plan for window function](https://explain.depesz.com/s/sGYu) - on a table with a million rows and an index on `count`